# Nested JSON to Kotlin Data Class

Tags: json, kotlin, fasterxml

I have Kotlin data classes `Things` and `Thing`

```
data class Things(val things: List<Thing>, 
                  val owner: String, 
                  val count: Int)
```

and

```
data class Thing(val name: String, 
                 val age: Int, 
                 val color: String)
```

and a service from which I receive JSON

```
fun getThings() : Things {
    val outsideResponse = callServiceForResponse()
    return objectMapper.readValue(outsideResponse.response)
}
```

where `outsideResponse.response` looks like this...

```
{
    "owner": "Foozy"
    "count": 2
    "THINGS": [
        {
             "name": {
                         "string": "Foo"
                     },
             "age": 2,
             "color": {
                          "string": "red"
                      }
        },

        {
             "name": {
                         "string": "Bar"
                     },
             "age": 3,
             "color": {
                          "string": "blue"
                      }
        }
    ]
}
```

What would be the simplest Kotlin-friendly way to achieve these data classes and deserialization?

I'm utilizing `import com.fasterxml.jackson.` and trying to not introduce any new dependencies.

In essence, I want to simply map something like

```
"name": {
         "string": "Foo"
        }
```

to `val name: String` without needing to create an additional

`data class ThingName( val name: String)`

Comment: Seems this tuto covers it nicely : https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/jackson-kotlin

Comment: Thanks Antoine, I've read through the deserialization sections but I'm not seeing the part which answers my question.

Comment: What complies you to go for including type in name field.
Default would be "name": "Foo", it is not possible to opt for this format ?
It would then be handled out of the box.

Comment: It's a response from a different service. Unfortunately, I can not change this.

Comment: OK. I believe @JsonFormat is the way to go : https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/json-format.html